# .Net Core or Mono include more namespaces?

Tags: .net-core, namespaces, mono

Does anyone know how to find a list of namespaces included in `.Net Core` (latest version 3.1) and those included in `Mono`?

I heard that `Mono` supports more namespaces than `.Net Core`, is this still true in 2020?

Comment: anything that supports .NET standard would be supported in both

Comment: could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Generally, based on the app you are trying to build you would look for classes (which would belong to namespaces), not find all namespaces, and put them together. Do take into account that there are countless namespaces supported in both

Comment: you can look for github repos such as this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries. it may help you find what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks @NevilleNazerane. To answer your question, I had a debate with someone who owns a server which runs on Ubuntu and uses Mono. He also mentioned experiencing some struggles using that framework and then I asked him why not use .NetCore. He claimed that Mono is more *powerfull* since it includes *more namespaces*. As a result I was wondering if that's true or not.

Comment: Most libraries (from NuGet for example) today support both, and probably more will only support .NET Core in the long run. So I wonder what kind of answer you wanted, number vs. number? That's not very likely to be counted, because 1) you have to crawl NuGet.org 2) There are other sources beyond NuGet, such as commercial libraries from various vendors. You'd better focus on more concrete requirements (like what kind of things you are looking for, database? UI frameworks? or others).

Comment: based on your reason for asking, this may go off StackOverflow soon. I suggest posting this question on any social media under .net community groups